# EF generates query with not supported minus sign in MS SQL (f.e. norvegian culture)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, cultureinfo

Consider app that sets culture at the beginning of the request. **It is must have**, as we are handling many things that are culture dependent in the whole pipeline:

```cs
//some where at the beginning of the code
var noCulture = new CultureInfo("nb-NO");
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = noCulture;
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = noCulture;
```

And then, somewhere on the bottom of code we have Entity Fremework (6.4.4) query:

```
var entities = (
     from record in _dbConterxt.Records
      //other joins etc, not relevant
      select new RecordDto
      {
          //other props, not relevant
          Status = Status ?? -1
      }
).ToList();
```

The issue is that query generated uses `U+2212 MINUS SIGN   nb Norwegian Bokmål` instead of
`U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS    en English`. Please take a look at the query generated::

```
CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[Status] IS NULL) THEN -1 ELSE [Filter1].[Status] END AS [C9],
```

It throws:

> An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the
> inner exception for details. Incorrect syntax near '−'. Incorrect
> syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

**Is it possible to fix it somehow without:**

1. ignoring culture (like I said, it is needed to handle other cases / places properly)
2. Rewriting query and getting rid of -1 (I know it is not the best approach but it is legacy code and we have other place like that).

Comment: I can't reproduce this using EF 6.4.4 + SQL Server. Also, the minus sign in your pasted SQL code is the correct character. I get the same error if I replace it by `U+2212` myself.

Comment: @GertArnold It looks like it got converted when copied it from internal teams. I've made direct text diff from SQL Profiler and that U+2212 is there for sure. 
The question is why you can't reproduce that. Maybe it has to sth running environment? Our code is running as azure function. But it would be strange to have different behaviors in different env, but not impossible.

Comment: Probably the culture on the database server also matters. I just run the code above (with a similar LINQ statement) in Linqpad. But then the SQL arrives in a server instance that has an English culture.

Comment: I would say the problem is that you are using EF 6 in 2024.

Comment: @IanKemp Not really helpful and it's likely that the same error occurs in EF core.

Comment: @IanKemp sometimes it's a case for legacy system 

Comment: @GertArnold I will check the culture on the db side. And will try to reproduce that on azure func project,maybe that's the issue 